# Pass value from form to button text vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am learning vb.net and I'm having issues searching for what I need.  I want to create a button that is "re-usable" throughout my application without needing to write code for each instance.  So, what I would like to start with is take a variable in a form, example, public integer value and when this value changes I want to write to the text of a button.  I know I can easily do this by writing code in the form btn_xxx.text = variable, but what if I have several buttons and each button looks at the same variable?  Currently what I do is create a component which inherits a button and have a timer that on tick will look at the variable and write to the text.  I'm sure there is a better way.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I know part of my problem is I don't know the nomenclature on what things are called, so hopefully I asked my question without too much confusion.

I saw this, https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/124842/detect-variable-change, but I don't see how to adapt that to my situation.

Here is what I have:

```
Private WithEvents Active_Alarm As New Nav_Active_Alarm
```

Then inside of a sub that calculates the count:

```
Active_Alarm.Count = CInt(dt_Active_Alarms.Rows.Count)
```

The user control:

```
Public Class Nav_Active_Alarm

Private mActive_Alarm_Count As Integer
Public Event Active_Alarm_Count_Changed(ByVal mvalue As Integer)
Public Property Count() As Integer
    Get
        Count = mActive_Alarm_Count
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mActive_Alarm_Count = value
        If Not Me.DesignMode Then
            RaiseEvent Active_Alarm_Count_Changed(mActive_Alarm_Count)
            test()
        End If

    End Set
End Property

Private Sub test()

    If Not Me.DesignMode Then

        If mActive_Alarm_Count = 0 Then
            Me.btn_Goto_Active_Alarm.Image = My.Resources.Alarm_Clock_Static
            'console or msgbox will work but updating the image will not
        Else
            Me.btn_Goto_Active_Alarm.Image = My.Resources.Alarm_Clock_Animation
                'console or msgbox will work but updating the image will not
            End If

    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

If I write to console or add a msgbox I will see the event working.  But, the image will not change.  If I call the test sub from a timer it will work.  Why won't the button update (by the way, I did try refresh and update in the code)?

Comment: This is not really about the `Button`. A regular `Button` will do just fine. What you really need to do is to use a property with a corresponding `Changed` event and then bind the `Text` property of each `Button` to that property. Whenever you change the property value, the event will be raised and that will prompt all the `Bindings` to update the `Buttons`.

Comment: Is what I asked possible? Not looking for other methods, just wondering if what I asked is possible. Also, not interested in opinions about how well I can swim. I have a reason for wanting to do this and it would take too much effort to explain. I'm basically wanting to create a library of simple components that all you have to do is drag and drop. Text is just one aspect, images, color, etc

Comment: Can anyone explain why the code I posted will not work?  If I call "test" from a timer tick it will work, but if I call from the event it will not, however, I can see the event working either by a console write or msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern is what you probably looking for.

This is quick and dirty.

Create a class to hold the variable value. Add a method that adds a button instance to a list.
Then a button that needs to know about the variable calls the register method.
When the value of the variable changes, it iterates through the list of buttons and sets the Text property of each one.

You might have jumped in a bit too deep too quick here. Google Custom data binding in .net, there's loads of built in stuff you can use. Though do it yourself is a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to do this might be:

1. Create a form level list to hold the buttons you are interested in
2. Add the buttons you are interested in, into the list (maybe in form load or some other place where you have initialization code)
3. Create a private property in your form with a backing variable to hold the value you want to have applied to the buttons. In the setter portion spin through the list and set each buttons text.

```
    Dim lstButtons As New List(Of Button)

    Sub SetupButtons()
        'call from form load or other init code
        lstButtons.Add(btnPopulate)
        lstButtons.Add(btnPopulate)
    End Sub


    Private _buttonText As String
    Private Property ButtonText As String
        Get
            Return _buttonText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _buttonText = value
            For Each b As Button In lstButtons
                b.Text = value
            Next
        End Set
    End Property
```

When you set the property - which now acts as your variable - it will update all of your textboxes for you.

I realize you mentioned without having to write code - but something has to tie things together.  Even if you used the observer pattern (which is an elegant solution for this - so props to those who suggested it) you'd probably end up creating a class to hold the property and have that class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged from System.ComponentModel, and then you'd also have to have each button have a databinding for its text property to the property in the object of your class.  There isn't really a way (that I can think of) to get around having to write some code for each form you do this in (though the class part you'd only have to write once of course).

Comment: The way I currently have it requires zero code, but it uses a timer, which I think is very clunky.  I'm sure it's just me not being able to ask the question correctly.  I will figure it out on my own.  Thanks.